# Specify required freshness of data from Data Cache

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql

I am using Invantive SQL for Exact Online to integrate BOARD with Exact Online. For caching, Invantive Data Cache is configured. By default the data remains fresh enough for the `/*+ ods */` hint to be used for 7 days.

I can switch the Data Cache fully off using `/*+ ods(false) */`, but how can I specify a different required freshness other than by dropping the internal tables maintained by Data Cache?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the conditions how old the data may be using the following syntax:

```
select /*+ ods(true, interval '1 millisecond') */ * from exactonlinerest..salesorders
```

The following interval units are available:

- millisecond(s)
- second(s)
- minute(s)
- hour(s)
- day(s)
- week(s)
- year(s)